# Chrome Extension Download API Failed - Forbidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to download all the images from a website and started off by using the example at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/downloads/download_links/. That basically gets all the links on the page and lets you download them

I confirmed that it worked when downloading link urls (.html), but when I changed it to included image urls (.jpg) it gave me the error Download Failed - Forbidden at the bottom of the webpage. Note that the images are hosted on a different website, but seeing as I can download other file types on other websites  and the image loads fine on the popup (which is also why I'm sure I used the correct urls), I'm not sure why I can't download the image directly.

Comment: Sounds like that site is using anti-hotlink protection. Google this term to find workarounds.

Comment: I would agree that that would seem to be the case but in that case I am confused as to why my <img> tags are loading the image? I would simply be able to write those images to a canvas and download it that way if chrome didn't specifically disallow that, which is why I'm using the API in the first place

Comment: img tags generate different headers in the network request.

Comment: I see. After examining the network the only difference I could find between accepted and forbidden headers was "sec-fetch-site," which was "cross-site" for the accepted request and "none" for the forbidden request. As chrome doesn't appear to allow you to modify this header, I suppose I fill have to find an alternative approach

Comment: Extensions can imitate that by using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders in `extraHeaders` mode and add/modify those headers for its own request via `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, then make a `Blob` and download it the standard DOM way.